# How exploit Get-ChildItem result?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I would like list all path to go to folder name ending with "_S" recursively.
I did that:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.Attributes -match "Directory") -and ($_.Name.EndsWith("_S") -and ($_.PSIsContainer -eq 1))}
```

But the result isn't an array. How i can to exploit the results ?
My goal is to have something like that:

- Myfolder\folder1\folder1_S
- Myfolder\folder2_S

Comment: Use Select-Object and grab the  FullName of the file

Comment: btw if `PSIsContainer` equals true that means it is a directory so the check on attributes is unnecessary (also  `-match` is normally used for regular expressions, in this case `-eq` would be the appropriate operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Select-Object` and grab the `FullName` of the file.

Also, as stated in the comments on the question by @Paul `($_.Attributes -match "Directory")` and `($_.PSIsContainer -eq 1)` is redundant, might want to remove one of them.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.Attributes -match "Directory") -and ($_.Name.EndsWith("_S"))} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

The above can also be refactored in PowerShell 3.0+, to

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Filter *_S | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

which would recursively get the path of all directories ending with "_S"

Comment: I'd suggest `ForEach-Object FullName` instead. Otherwise you get a new object that has a single property instead of just the string. Well, or just don't use string paths at all if you can help it. It's a bad idea in general in PowerShell.

Comment: or select -expandproperty to just get the value

Comment: Thanks, included -expandproperty

Comment: Nice thx, i using the first command because my Powershell version doesn't support `Get-ChildItem -Directory`

Comment: @Ferfa what version of powershell are you using?

Comment: I using PSVersion 2.0 and i working on Windows 7. The second command works on Windows Server 2012 (PSVersion 4.0)

Comment: Ok updated tag on question and updated answer to reflect appropriately

Comment: @Paul fixed it. Also included your comment in the answer for reference.